# Objective C: Detecting a Voice

Tags: objective-c, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording

Good day! i just want to ask if what value should i need to input in my code and inside the condition in order to detect a regular voice of a user, in such that after i detected the voice, i will record it automatically and stop the recording when it is silent/the recorder didnt detect the voice, this is my code and i get that from [detecting when a user blows into the mic.](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/)

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

    [recorder record];
    if (lowPassResults < 0.95)
        {NSLog(@"Recording");
             [recorder record];}

}
```

im new at objective c, any help would be very helpful to me... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set level you can use to detect the volume of normal speech. Leaving aside issues of background noise and so on, There is no standard translation between audio levels as numbers in a computer and sound levels in the air.

Think about it: what are the input levels? What type of mike is it? How far away is the user? You don't know any of these things, so there's no way to know the answer.

You might want to think about looking for relative change in volume, rather than absolute level (although this is iffy as well) or a different user experience entirely.

Comment: how will i able to record an audio at the moment i detected it

Comment: That is a different question, but the short answer is to buffer you audio so you actually record a little ahead of when you detect something. The appropriate datastructure for that is usually called a ringbuffer.